Wampserver: Updating mysql version but used version is still 5.7.19
I have been trying for hours to update my mysql version for wampserver, and i'm stuck in V5.7.19.
Even if localhost/ root show "Mysql version 8.2.0", when I go to localhost/phpmyadmin, login with "root":"", the right panel show version 5.7.19
"Version du serveur : 5.7.19 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)"
https://imgur.com/a/qmT5wUB
I even restarted my computer, installed all C++ drivers, updated PHP version to V8, updated phpmyadmin, but mysql is stuck at this version and I don't understand why.
Thanks for help.

Maybe you have multiple installations of MySql? Wamps has own installation of MySql. All your screenshots shows MySql version 8.2

@Justinas Yes but on phpmyadmin (from wamp) it show 5.7.19

@Justinas SELECT version(); return 5.7.19 from console and from phpmyadmin

Phpmyadmin is a completely separate tool from mysql. If you installed another version of mysql, then phpmyadmin will not magically point to the new installation. You need to manually configure it

I don't know how to do this and didn't found any documentation about this, I uninstalled WAMP and reinstalled and everything was updated. I lost time for nothing sadly
